# AJAX Workflow editor, AML file not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, xaml, editor

Hey i am trying to build a workflow editor in a asp.net web project. I have done quite some research on this, and found some ways to do it, but i went with this

http://ui.ajax.org/#demos/elements.flowchart

In this i have updated all the .xml and .js files on my project, but i am having problem with the AML part, i have tried including all the links mentioned here

http://ui.ajax.org/#docs/getting_started.creating a new project

I just cant get it to work and i cant find any tutorials online too. I would really appreciate it if any one can help me through this

PS if you knw any alternative, please let me know